# Instantiating a class dynamically from a string

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

Good afternoon fellow developers,

I am currently trying to develop a function that instantiates business objects dynamically based on the value of the string it receives as a parameter. I know this can be done in JavaScript as I have done it before and, just to be sure, I even tested it again in Visual Studio Code after having encountered this issue in my SAPUI5 app. My function's code looks somewhat like this:

```
        createObject: function (sObject) {
    
    var newObject = new this[sObject]();
    // var newObject = new [sObject](); I also tried this way.
    
    };
```

For the sake of testing this function, the sObject string currently contains the hardcoded value "Order" and I am importing my Order.js object into the file where i'm trying to instantiate this objects dynamically. No matter what I try I keep getting this error when debugging my code:

`TypeError: this[sObject] is not a constructor`

I was wondering if some of you might have tried something similar before and might be able to point me in the right direction. Even if there are ways for me to work around this issue, it would be really nice if I learnt how to do this dynamically since I was planning on using this approach on several different scenarios. I look forward to reading from you!

Comment: the new keyword can only be used in place of a constructor you have defined or an inbuilt one like Array, Object, Number, and so on

Comment: So calling `new Order()` would work? And you're expecting e.g. `new "Order"()`?

Comment: What are "business objects" in your context?

Comment: Yes, calling new Order() works because the Order class is being imported into the layer where i'm trying to build the objects dynamically.

Comment: `new Order()` !== `new this.Order()`, I think your looking for `new window[sObject]` instead. Please show all of your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

It is a really unsafe practice to instantiate objects from a string and an ATROCIOUS one to do it from a parameter a user can supply.  If you have a limited set of objects its much safer to have a big switch statement.

```
switch(name) {
   "objA": return new ObjA();
}
```

Comment: These strings won't ever be from user input, they will be hardcoded. The reason I'm trying to do this dynamically is because this will be part of a multi-layered architecture "framework" that will work for any SAP module. The code inside the framework will be prepared to handle SAP objects in one layer, and perform CRUD operations in the data access layer. Apps using this framework will only have to pass the name of the objects they need (depending on the SAP module they are based on). While the number of objects will be limited, I feel like a switch statement for them would be quite large.

Comment: Outside of security, Reflection can have a large impact on performance when used. I understand the desire to make things flexible but dynamic object instantiation can resist JIT optimization. It also doesnt make for a very clear api.  If someone knows already knows the class they want are you really helping anything by making them go through an indirect process?